# Why is Beach ビーチ and not ビーチュ, why is Cake ケーキ and not ケーク?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, phonology

The latter sounds better, in my opinion. But is that just my opinion?

Comment: Why is karaoke pronounced carry-okee in English?

Comment: @Ciaran Good point.

Comment: definitely jut your opinion. Japanese English' Katakana is not made by English proficient people. As long as the phonetic sound is close enough, it is good. Besides, there are not only one English in this world.

Answer (score 5):

ビーチ for *beach* is regular, but ケーキ for *cake* needs some explanation.

English //tʃ// and //dʒ// stand as closing consonant are always transcribed as チ and ジ, contrary to //ʃ// in the same position as シュ (with a handful of exception, such as サッシ "sash"). This is perhaps related to rare presence of チュ and ジュ as short syllables in Japanese words. Note that, however, similar consonants in German and French are usually transcribed as チュ and ジュ.

English //-ɪk// ending first had been transcribed -キ, reflecting the fact that the consonant is slightly palatalized because of preceding vowel value. After systematic transcription system was established, all //-k// have been automatically replaced with ク, but old words that have already taken root never changed. As a result:

- ケーキ "cake" ←→ no counterpart
- ストライキ "labor strike" ←→ ストライク "(other) strike"
- ステーキ "steak" ←→ ステイク "stake(-holder)"
- ブレーキ "brake" ←→ ブレーク/ブレイク "break"
- レーキ "rake", "[lake pigment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_pigment)" ←→ レイク "lake"
- ミルクセーキ "(traditional) milk shake" ←→ シェーキ ([Lotteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotteria)) ←→ シェイク (McDonald's)

cf. "makeup": [メーキャップ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%22) (1M hits) vs [メイクアップ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%22) (14M hits) vs [メークアップ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%22) (463k hits)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question and not sure which sounds better to me but I guess words that end with `ch` tend to be pronounced `チ` instead of `チュ`.

For example,

- teach ティーチ
- coach　コーチ
- bleach　ブリーチ
- reach　リーチ
- touch　タッチ
- match　マッチ

and words that end with `ke` is pronounced either `ク` or `キ`　but I see more `ク`

For example,

- lake レイク
- bake ベイク
- fake　フェイク
- make　メイク
- take　テイク
- like ライク
- joke　ジョーク
- cake　ケーキ
- brake　ブレーキ

Comment: Text テキスト is an example where テクストsounds better IMHO